# SQL query about a right or full join with date table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to the sql world and trying to archive a certain result.

I have two tables: Table A contains, among other things, the following columns: Market_ID, Date, Event

```
| Market_ID | Date           | Event |
| --------  | -------------- |------ |
| 1         | 2023-01-06     | F     |
| 1         | 2023-04-07     | F     |
| 2         | 2023-01-06     | F     |
```

where the column event also contains other strings than 'F', but only 'F' is relevant for me. In addition, the column date does not contain all dates within a year. It only has an entry if there is an event on this day.

Table B is a date table just containing all dates in different formats within a year from the past and future

```
| Date_Day   | Date_Week      |        
| ---------- | -------------- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023/01        |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023/01        |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023/01        |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023/01        |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023/01        |
| 2023-01-06 | 2023/01        |
| ...        | ...            |
```

My expected output should be a table containing all dates and an additional column whether there was an Event F on that day or not:

```
| Market_ID | Date           | Is_EVENT_F|
| --------  | -------------- |---------- |
| 1         | 2023-01-01     | 0         |
| 1         | 2023-01-02     | 0         |
| 1         | 2023-04-03     | 0         |
| 1         | 2023-04-04     | 0         |
| 1         | 2023-04-05     | 0         |
| 1         | 2023-01-06     | 1         |
```

I have tried using either an right or outer join but in both cases, the result was not correct.

Comment: Start with TableB, left outer join TableA and then use a CASE statement to set Is_EVENT_F

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    A.Market_ID, 
    B.Date_Day as Date, 
    CASE WHEN A.Event = 'F' 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as Is_EVENT_F
FROM TABLE_B B
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A A
ON A.Date = B.Date_day
```

But this query is obviously going to return null Market_id for the dates in which there is no record in TABLE_A.

Comment: *this query is obviously going to return nulls for the dates* ... including `A.Market_ID` !!

Comment: @Akina Yes, that's what I acually meant. The dates won't be NULL but Market_id will be in fact NULL.

Comment: And what is the reason? you even have no chance to sort the rows for to see that some market and date data is absent - even visually.

Comment: @Akina If you there is no that data for a given date, you can't do a miracle. I have tested your solution and it doesn't seem to work btw: https://sqltest.net/#1669402

Comment: You're absolutely correct - I loose the condition by the date. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Inner SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    market_id
    , b.date_day
    , IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM table_a a2 WHERE to_char(a2.date_day) = to_char(b.date_day) AND a2.market_id = a.market_id), 0) is_event_f
FROM
    table_b b
        CROSS JOIN table_a a;
```

Comment: Thre is no `to_char()` function in MySQL. After fixing this problem your query will produce duplicates in the output and `1` for each row despite of  `event` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
SELECT C.Market_ID, B.Date_Day, 
       CASE WHEN A.Event IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Is_EVENT_F  
FROM table_b B 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Market_ID FROM table_a) C
     LEFT JOIN table_a A ON (A.Market_ID = C.Market_ID AND A.Date1 = B.Date_Day AND Event = 'F') 
ORDER BY C.Market_ID, B.Date_Day
```

Comment: Your query won't show markets which have no `'F'` rows.

Comment: Now your query will show `1` for all markets if at least one of them have `'F'` for this date. See https://dbfiddle.uk/hxawHzH1 last query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.Market_ID, B.Date_Day AS Date, 
       CASE WHEN A.Event = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_EVENT_F
FROM TBL_Date B
LEFT JOIN TBL_MarketPlace A ON B.Date_Day = A.Date
```

Comment: `A.Market_ID` in the output will produce NULLs for non-existing dates.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT markets.market_id,
       dates.date_day `date`,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM table_a
                WHERE market_id = markets.market_id 
                  AND date1 = dates.date_day
                  AND event = 'F' ) is_event_f
FROM table_b dates
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT market_id 
             FROM table_a ) markets
-- ORDER BY ...
```

Subquery `markets` gather all markets list. If markets table exisrts then use it instead.

Joining this subquery and dates list generates all possible pairs market-date.

Subquery in EXISTS checks does the row with `'F'` exists for each market at each date.

https://dbfiddle.uk/-CVLgaV4